# Change OutputEncoding and code page

Tags: windows-10, powershell, encoding, unicode

I was having some trouble getting Unicode output with PowerShell, which I
partially solved using this:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

However I noticed that this setting has an issue. If I run a command like this:

```
Get-Content a.txt
```

It does not output in UTF8. It seems this is the reason:

> Default Uses the encoding that corresponds to the system's active code page
>   (usually ANSI).

https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1

So if `[Console]::OutputEncoding` doesnt change the Code Page, then what does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse to this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
```

and change `OEMCP` to `65001`. Then restart. With this fix, if you are using
Consolas font, it seems to lock PowerShell into a small font size. `cmd.exe`
still works fine. As a workaround, you can use Lucida Console, or I switched
to Cascadia Mono:

https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code

Comment: Have you tested this? I've just added `chcp 65001` to my $profile file and restarted powershell. It outputs "Active code page: 65001" as expected but `get-content` still doesn't work correctly unless the test file is BOM encoded.

Comment: `$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`

Comment: @monkey no, thats not a complete solution. It fails with `Get-Content`, as detailed in the original post

Answer (score 2):

#### If `[Console]::OutputEncoding` doesn't change the Code Page, then what does?

According to [Set the default encoding to UTF-8 in powershell](https://gist.github.com/xoner/4671514) you should be using:

> ```
> [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
> ```

Which is slightly different from the command you are using.

> Another way is to use chcp.com:
>
> ```
> & "$env:windir\system32\chcp.com" 65001
> ```

---

#### After testing it seems like powershell likes to work with BOM encoded UTF8 files.

If your files are not BOM encoded you can use `-encoding utf8`.

Example with a non BOM encoded UTF8 file:

```
> get-content test.txt
Greek (in Polytonic):

  The Greek anthem:

  Î£á½² Î³Î½Ï‰Ïá½·Î¶Ï‰ á¼€Ï€á½¸ Ï„á½´Î½ Îºá½¹ÏˆÎ·
  Ï„Î¿á¿¦ ÏƒÏ€Î±Î¸Î¹Î¿á¿¦ Ï„á½´Î½ Ï„ÏÎ¿Î¼ÎµÏá½µ,
  Ïƒá½² Î³Î½Ï‰Ïá½·Î¶Ï‰ á¼€Ï€á½¸ Ï„á½´Î½ á½„ÏˆÎ·
  Ï€Î¿á½º Î¼á½² Î²á½·Î± Î¼ÎµÏ„Ïá½±ÎµÎ¹ Ï„á½´ Î³á¿†.

  á¾¿Î‘Ï€á¾¿ Ï„á½° Îºá½¹ÎºÎºÎ±Î»Î± Î²Î³Î±Î»Î¼á½³Î½Î·
  Ï„á¿¶Î½ á¿¾Î•Î»Î»á½µÎ½Ï‰Î½ Ï„á½° á¼±ÎµÏá½±
  ÎºÎ±á½¶ Ïƒá½°Î½ Ï€Ïá¿¶Ï„Î± á¼€Î½Î´ÏÎµÎ¹Ï‰Î¼á½³Î½Î·
  Ï‡Î±á¿–ÏÎµ, á½¦ Ï‡Î±á¿–ÏÎµ, á¾¿Î•Î»ÎµÏ…Î¸ÎµÏÎ¹á½±!
> get-content test.txt -encoding utf8
Greek (in Polytonic):

  The Greek anthem:

  Σὲ γνωρίζω ἀπὸ τὴν κόψη
  τοῦ σπαθιοῦ τὴν τρομερή,
  σὲ γνωρίζω ἀπὸ τὴν ὄψη
  ποὺ μὲ βία μετράει τὴ γῆ.

  ᾿Απ᾿ τὰ κόκκαλα βγαλμένη
  τῶν ῾Ελλήνων τὰ ἱερά
  καὶ σὰν πρῶτα ἀνδρειωμένη
  χαῖρε, ὦ χαῖρε, ᾿Ελευθεριά!
>
```

Comment: See [Understanding file encoding in VS Code and PowerShell - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-7) "There is no way for PowerShell to automatically determine the file encoding."

Comment: I want to emphasize `powershell` and `.net` docs and libraries may say `unicode` when they mean `ut16-le`  -- **not `unicode` generically**. (even) Powershell core 7's `get-content -Encoding unicode` means `utf16 little endian` -- The `.net` docs have details the `powershell` docs don't include [.net encoding and System.Text docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding)